# Apache commons Fileupload vs Tomcat.util.http.fileupload

Tags: file-upload, apache-commons

I saw these two libraries can help me to upload file to the webserver. I end up using Apache commons lib but was wondering whether they provide some advantage over each other or they are just two different implementation to do the same job.
Further , we have the options available in easy form if we are using servlet 3.0 through request.getParts().

Thanks and Regards
Surya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend sticking to the Apache Commons API to keep the code independent from the server it's deployed on. Starting with Tomcat 7 the servlet 3.0 API is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already implemented using Apache Commons API and java NIO Libraries .. and they are working great !